# removing the 180 degrees phaseshift at the secondary of transformer

Tags: transformer

me and my group are designing a PMU(phasor measurement unit) prototype.we need to step down the 220v AC input upto 12v by a t/f.till here everything goes ok..but PMU is meant to measure the phase ,frequency and magnitude of the incoming ac signal.now,if we get 180 degrees phaseshift by a transformer,we are afraid it can be erroneous.can it be removed by something?

Comment: Welcome to SE.EE Please use proper punctuation.

Comment: Why don't you just at 180deg phase to your measurement?

Comment: And please use capital letters where required and a space after every punctuation mark. "t/f.till" isn't a recognised abbreviation. Between you and your group you should be able to manage. ;^)

Comment: hmmm...inverter gate, inverting transistor/amp stage, or any one of about 50 other very commonly used methods....oh yeah, kr just switch the wires and **poof** instant 180 phase change again.

Comment: that's exactly what came to my mind yesterday..we are actually doing the computations on Raspberry Pi and so we can compensate for the phase shift in it too. Plus I figured out one more method but I am not sure if that would work: We would be using a square wave to compare the incoming sine wave with it in order to have the phase shift. If we can generate the square wave through an OPAMP , can the shift be compensated? since  I have learned that OPAMP produces 180 shift?

Answer (score 1):

> if we get 180 degrees phaseshift by a transformer,we are afraid it can
>   be erroneous.can it be removed by something?

Swap the output wires over is the very simple fix. The next easiest fix is to swap the input wires over.

If you are also worried by small phase errors due to loading conditions changing then ensure the load is constant and resistive. As for changes in frequency, this will add phase errors so be careful there. Even amplitude variations can move the phase angle slightly if on the verge of saturation (too much primary voltage at too low a frequency).

Comment: thank you so much.i just have one more query.u mentioned amplitude variations can move the phase angle...that thing! i didnt get that.could u plz explain?

Comment: If you are close to core saturation, an increase in amplitude creates even more saturation and the primary magnetization inductance starts to rapidly fall and you get a phase shift in the signal.